# Regex - count all numbers

Tags: c++, regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern that returns true if found 7 numbers on given string. There's no order so if a string is set to: "100 my, str1ng y000" it catches that.

Comment: Do you want _exactly_ 7 numbers or _at least_ 7 numbers? What language/tool are you using?

Comment: At least 7 numbers. Btw, it's c++ language

Comment: Something like this would be better done another way, for example in JavaScript you could do `input.match(/\d/g).length >= 7` - otherwise, if a regex is required, you're stuck with `(?:\D*\d){7}` which is unintuitive.

Comment: Simple: `(\d.*){7}`

Comment: You mean 7 **digits**, right? Because there are 7 digits in the sample string you posted, i.e. (in order of appearance in string from left to right) 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.

Comment: _Thread solved_ @k2iron kindly post your solution.

Comment: @Abra - given the situation, Niet the Dark Absol & Barmar both their versions worked pretty good.

Comment: Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol, It worked for me to count digits on a given string. Slightly modified to get exactly 10 digits: `(?:\D*\d\D*){10}`, and it looks like it can be used to get ranges too `{n,m}`

Answer (score 0):

RegEx alone won't count exact occurrences for you, it would return true even if there are more than 7 digits in the string because it would try to find out at least 7 digits in the string.

You can use below code to test exact number (7 in your case) of digits in any string:

```
var temp = "100 my, str1ng y000  3c43fdgd";
var count = (temp.match(/\d/g) || []).length;
alert(count == 7);
```

Comment: Why do you give a javascript answer to a c++ question?

Answer (score 0):

I will show you an C++ Example that

- Shows a regex for extracting digit groups
- Shows a regex for matching at least 7 digits
- Shows, if there is a match for the requested predicate
- Shows the number of digits in the string (no regex needed)
- Shows the group of digits

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

// Our test data (raw string). So, containing also \" and so on
std::string testData("100 my, str1ng y000");

std::regex re1(R"#((\d+))#");       // For extracting digit groups 
std::regex re2(R"#((\d.*){7,})#");  // For regex match

int main(void)
{
    // Define the variable id as vector of string and use the range constructor to read the test data and tokenize it
    std::vector<std::string> id{ std::sregex_token_iterator(testData.begin(), testData.end(), re1, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator() };

    // Match the regex. Should have at least 7 digits somewhere
    std::smatch base_match;
    bool containsAtLeast7Digits = std::regex_match(testData, base_match, re2);

    // Show result on screen
    std::cout << "\nEvaluating string  '" << testData << 
        "'\n\nThe predicate 'contains-at-leats-7-digits' is " << std::boolalpha << containsAtLeast7Digits <<
        "\n\nIt contains overall " <<
        std::count_if(
            testData.begin(), 
            testData.end(), 
            [](const char c) {
                return std::isdigit(static_cast<int>(c)); 
            }
        ) << " digits and " << id.size() << " digit groups. These are:\n\n";

    // Print complete vector to std::cout
    std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Please note: Use `std::count` for counting. Faster and easier.
Hope this helps . . .